# Multiple LIKE and AND operators in RAILS/POSTGRESQL

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, rails-activerecord

I'm using Rails 5.0.1 and Postgresql as my database. I have a table with column `:content` which contains words.

**The problem:** When I'm looking for a specific word, I want to see if the word contains letters (chars) of my choice. Let's say i want to DB to return words containg letters "a", "b" and "c" (all of them, but with no specific order)

**What I'm doing:** I found that i could use 
`Word.where("content like ?", "%a%").where("content like ?", "%b%").where("content like ?", "%c%")` 
 OR
`Word.where("content like ? content like ? content like ?", "%a%", "%b%", "%c%")`
In both cases even if i switch order of given letters/substrings it works fine, ex. both would find word "back", "cab" etc..

**The question:** Is there any better/more **DRY** way to do it? What if want to find word with 8 different letters? Do i have to use "content like ?" 8 times? Is it possible to pass arguments as an array? (let's assume i don't know how many letters user will input)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PostgreSQL has a handy [`expr op all (array)`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-comparisons.html#AEN20967) expression so you can say things like:

```
where content like all (array['%a%', '%b%', '%c'])
```

as a short form of:

```
where content like '%a%'
  and content like '%b%'
  and content like '%c%'
```

Also, ActiveRecord will conveniently replace a `?` placeholder with a comma-delimited list if you hand it a Ruby array. That lets you say things like:

```
Word.where('content like all (array[?])', %w[a b c].map { |c| "%#{c}%" })
```

and:

```
Word.where('content like all (array[?])', some_other_array.map { |c| "%#{c}%" })
```

Comment: thanks for great answer! i also tried to use SIMILAR TO but it was incredibly slow. This is exactly what i was looking for

Comment: There are also some [indexing options](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13452528/479863) that work with LIKE.

Answer (score 2):

I found a solution:

```
letters = ["%a%", "%b%", "%c%"]
Word.where((['content LIKE ?'] * letters.size).join(' AND '), *letters)
```

This is easy and much better than I was using.

Answer (score 0):

I think the [`SIMILAR TO`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-matching.html) operator might help. It allows you to pass in a regular expression that you could construct on the fly.

```
letters = ['a', 'b', 'c']
pattern = "%(#{letters.join('|')})%"
Word.where("content SIMILAR TO ?", pattern)
```

Comment: This pattern doesn't use all of the letters. It uses one, or two, or all of them, or first and fifth etc. I want to use all of given letters, but not in any particular order