# Matching string against keywords

Tags: postgresql, text, keyword, matching, sql-like

I have a field which contains text string, for example:

```
Credit for an item
Credit for menu
Debit for food
Credit for food
Debit for Delivery
Etc.
```

I want to categorize them into two categories impacting and none impacting adjustments

I am trying to write this expression in SQL:

```
If "Text_string" contain "Keywords: Food, Delivery", then "Impacting" else "None Impacting"
```

Thanks very much in advance

Comment: Is it any of those two keywords or all of them? If it is any then this is a duplicate of [**PostgreSQL wildcard LIKE for any of a list of words**](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4928054/479863). If it is all then this is a duplicate of [**Multiple LIKE and AND operators in RAILS/POSTGRESQL**](http://stackoverflow.com/q/42124181/479863).

Answer (score 0):

```
select  case
        when text_string ilike '%food%' and 
             text_string ilike '%delivery%' then 'Impacting'
        else 'None impacting'
        end as IsImpacting
from    YourTable
```

Comment: text_string ilike '%food%' and text_string ilike '%delivery%' then 'Impacting'   or text_string ilike '%food%' or text_string ilike '%delivery%' then 'Impacting'